# storing data so it is globally available in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my project I am calling the rest API which result gives a list of Map. 
my App has 4 bottomtab options, in Dashboard I am hitting the API, and I am doing some operations on the data, but I need the result of that API should be available to all the tabs, else I have to hit again and store in that dart file,

Is there any way whrere I can Hit once and store it into a map and I can use that all over my project?

thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook#persistence) for disk storage or [this](https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter#state-management) for state managment.

Answer (score 2):

Create a static List variable of your Data by Creating a new Class named Global

```
class Global
{
   static List<MYDataClass> MyDataList = List();
}
```

to Add Data pass Object of MYDataClass

```
MyDataList.add(MYDataClass())
```

to Access it

```
Global.MyDataList[index].property;
```

Hope this Help...